# Mongoose nested object not updating 'cannot create field "foo" in element'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a similar issue to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670619/mongodb-cannot-create-field-x-in-element).

I'm trying to create a new field using "findAndUpdate". I've tried all the methods, $set, $push, $addSet... none of them seem to be working and I keep getting the same error.

Here's the code:

```
router.post('/accept', auth, async (req, res) => {        
  const useremail = user.email
  const originalEvent = await Event.findOneAndUpdate({eventId: 61469041, isOrganizer: true, "attendees.email": useremail},
            {"$push":{"attendees.status" : "accepted"}},
            {new: true})
            res.status(200).json({originalEvent, event})
          
          } 
          catch (e) {
          res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message, success: false });
        }
        });
```

Here's the error code:

```
"Cannot create field 'status' in element {attendees: [ { _id: ObjectId('5f80a02a82dceb2810e0aa66'), email: "bob@gmail.com", name: "Bob" } ]}"
```

Here's the object I'm trying to update:

```
{
    "organizer": {
      "email": "alex@gmail.com",
      "name": "Alex"
    },
    "_id": "5f80a02a82dceb2810e0aa65",
    "title": "Go to the beach",
    "eventId": 61469041,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "user": "5f05f23417ca6ab69ccc4cf2",
    "attendees": [
      {
        "_id": "5f80a02a82dceb2810e0aa66",
        "email": "bob@gmail.com",
        "name": "Bob"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
  }
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
    "organizer": {
      "email": "alex@gmail.com",
      "name": "Alex"
    },
    "_id": "5f80a02a82dceb2810e0aa65",
    "title": "Go to the beach",
    "eventId": 61469041,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "user": "5f05f23417ca6ab69ccc4cf2",
    "attendees": [
      {
        "_id": "5f80a02a82dceb2810e0aa66",
        "email": "bob@gmail.com",
        "name": "Bob",
        "status": "accepted"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
  }
```

SOLVED with this:

```
  const originalEvent = await Event.findOneAndUpdate({eventId: eventId, "isOrganizer": true, 
    "attendees": {$elemMatch: {email: useremail}}
  },
    { $set: { "attendees.$.status": "accepted"} }
      )
    
    res.status(200).json(originalEvent)
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing `attendees.status` doesn't make sense because in your schema `attendees` is not an object (with fields such as `status`) but an array. But you can do it differently. If you have the index of the attendee you want to mutate, you can do `{ $set: { "attendees.0.status": "accepted" } }`, where `0` is the index in the array.

---

Also, with regards to the first half of your question, the error you're seeing is because `$push` works on arrays. So in order for your operation to work, you'd have to first initialize such an object `{attendees: { status: [] } }`.

> If the field is not an array, the operation will fail. ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push))